# What is the difference between object x = null and object x = (object) null?

Tags: c#, .net

What is the difference between `object x = null` and `object x = (object) null` in C#?

**Edit** - I haven't personally used this code. I wanted to know how MVC route handling works so opened [this](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/RouteCollectionExtensions.cs) to understand it and found `(object) null` used in it. so want to know the difference.

Comment: Have you noticed any difference when you run both code?

Comment: Eser I edited the question to add more detail.

Comment: I don't know why someone down voted this question. I don't know the difference, if there is no difference why does MVC framework cast null to object?

Comment: Answered your question about why ASP.NET uses it like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the specific example you provided (why it is used like that in the ASP.NET source code) the answer is: yes, it makes a difference whether the `(object)` cast is there or not.

We have this method:

```
public static Route MapRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url)
{
    return MapRoute(routes, name, url, null /* defaults */, (object)null /* constraints */);
}
```

Lets assume we call it like this:

```
RouteCollection.MapRoute(routes, "SomeName", "SomeUrl");
```

Because the `(object)null` cast is in this method, the following method will be called:

```
public static Route MapRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, object defaults, object constraints)
{
    return MapRoute(routes, name, url, defaults, constraints, null /* namespaces */);
}
```

Because the last parameter is explicitly `object` (we casted to that).

Without the cast the following method would be called:

```
public static Route MapRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, object defaults, string[] namespaces)
{
    return MapRoute(routes, name, url, defaults, null /* constraints */, namespaces);
}
```

So basically, the cast is there as an aid to choose the more specific method over the less specific.

You can test it yourself with a simpler example:

```
public static class TestClass
{
    public static void TestMethod(object parameter)
    {
    }

    public static void TestMethod(string[] parameter)
    {
    }
}
```

And then call:

```
TestClass.TestMethod(null); // will call TestMethod(string[] parameter)

TestClass.TestMethod((object)null); // will call TestMethod(object parameter)
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing.

Visual Studio will probably even tell you that the explicit cast is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference both will set x to null.

```
public static void Main()
{
    object a =  (object)null; // casts null to object basically creating a null object and assigning it to a making it null
    object b =  null; // directly assigns b the value of null
    Console.WriteLine(a == b);
}
```

There might be a negligible overhead when casting null to object as opposed to just setting it to null.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/elilu7

To further confirm that there is no difference and using OPs reference to Microsofts own code in the System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions.cs, which would add validity to OPs question:

```
//This method cast to object
public static Route MapRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url)
{
    return MapRoute(routes, name, url, null /* defaults */, (object)null /* constraints */);
}

//This method does not
public static Route MapRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, string[] namespaces)
{
    return MapRoute(routes, name, url, null /* defaults */, null /* constraints */, namespaces);
}
```